# detached elements memory leak, summary points to internal node

Tags: javascript, dom, memory-leaks

I am working on performance and trying to see if my app has any memory leaks. Every time i ran my app and clear state, there are some detached nodes. When trying to see summary, its pointint to internal node, can't find anything which points to my code.

here is screenshot of heap snapshot

[image]

When i ran the app again and again, the memory seems to be same but there is always detached elements. I also tried comparision between different snapshots and delta is zero.

here is screenshot of comparision

[image]

Can anyone tell me if there is memory leak in my app or is it fine (this is normal) ?

If this is normal, then i would like to know why there are detached nodes, and if it is not, please tell me how to fix it.